# Draw multiple rectangles on canvas overlay over a video, every second according to coordinates stored within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, settimeout, detect

So I have a video upon which I must draw rectangles over multiple faces at the same time. Those rectangles must move according to the movement of those faces. I have an array which stores the info regarding the position of the rectangles for every frame.

On video play I resize the canvas so it covers the entire video except for the buttons.

```
$(".video-detect").on("play", function resize_canvas() {
            var w = this.offsetWidth;
            var h = this.offsetHeight;
            canvas = document.getElementById("cv1");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h - 75;

            draw();
        });
```

I call the draw function after getting the canvas and context reference.
Here I try to at least draw every second of the video not every frame.

```
function draw() {
           var time = $(".video-detect")[0].duration;
           var i = 0;
           for (let k = 1; k < time; k++) {
               setTimeout(function () {
                   var objArray = [{}];
                   for (; i < facesObject.length; i++) {
                       var x = facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[0],//x1 coordinate
                           y = facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[1],//y1 coordinate
                           width = facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[2] - facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[0],//x2 - x1 coordinate
                           height = facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[3] - facesObject[i].Frame_idx[k].Coordinates[1];//y2 - y1 coordinate

                      // If i draw the rect here with x y width height params I have trouble clearing the canvas for redraw the next iteration
                   }
                   console.log(k);
               }, k * 1000);
           }
       }
```

Comment: @Luceafarul, I am trying to solve the same problem you've mentioned here. Did you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: I gave up the overlay idea and made the drawings on a plain image with a slider that mimicked the passing of time changing the rectangles drawn.